# java random password generator code to include special characters

Tags: java, random

I written java code to random generate password using Date but I got stuck up add meet the below criteria in the code to include special characters. As I am new to java how to satisfy the below criteria of special characters in my code. please help on this.

It should contain at least one capital case letter.

It should contain at least one lower-case letter.

It should contain at least one number.

Length should be 8 characters.

It should contain one of the following special characters: @, $, #, !.

```
 private static String[] alpha = new String[] 
         {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j",
    "k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};

     private static String[] specialChars = new String[]{"!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&",
    "*"};

  private static int NUMBER_LETTERS = 7;
private static int NUMBER_ALPHABET = 26;

public class passwordGenerator implements Runnable {

    private String randomStr = null;
    public void run() {
        StringBuffer password = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            Date d = new Date();
            long currentTime = d.getTime();

            //First pick 6 letters and convert the randomly selected one to lowercase
            int lowerCaseIndex = (int) (currentTime % NUMBER_LETTERS);
            int timeStep = 1739;
            currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            for(int letterIndex = 0; letterIndex < NUMBER_LETTERS; letterIndex++) {

                //Pick a letter
                int randomNo = (int) (currentTime % NUMBER_ALPHABET);
                String letter = alpha[randomNo];
                if(letterIndex != lowerCaseIndex) {
                    letter = letter.toUpperCase();
                }
                password.append(letter);
                currentTime += timeStep;
            }
            Thread.sleep(200);
            currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            int number = (int) (currentTime % 10);
            password.append(String.valueOf(number));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error occurred while generating the random password!", e);
            Thread.currentThread().destroy();
        }

        randomStr = password.toString();
    }
    /**
     * @return the randomStr
     */
    public String getRandomStr() {
        return randomStr;
    }
```

Comment: What part(s) of this are you having trouble with, and what *specifically* is that trouble?

Comment: code not add the special characters logic

Comment: What is preventing you from adding that code?

Comment: By the way, the terrible `Date` classes were years ago supplanted by he modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. To represent a moment as seen in UTC, use `Instant`.  To get a count of milliseconds since first moment of 1970 in UTC, call `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()`.

Comment: Add clarifications as edits to the Question rather than as Comments.